# How can you detect if a facebook embedded post is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-ui

I'm building a facebook app which needs to display the actual facebook post along the way. This is fine but if the post to display goes away or the privacy settings are wrong, how can you detect this and take other action, rather than show the post is not viewable. I was thinking to open the post in a separate tab. But I can't get into the iframe to see whats happening

I put together a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfWxG/5/) to demonstrate it - the invalid post isn't a post but I think details the problem as the post could have been deleted

```
    //if(check for nolonger available message){
          console.log($("fb-post").contents().find('body').html);
    //    alert("open another tab");
    //}else{
    var menu = $('#postmenu').show().position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "right bottom",
        of: this
    });
    //}

    return false;
}
```